# Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::getRealPath()

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got a client who has just set up a new VPN and is attempting to install my plugin.

He's getting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::getRealPath() on the commented line below. This appears to have something to do with the ZEND libraries. Any ideas what I should tell him to do?

Comment: Tell him to upgrade to a PHP version that hasn't reached End of Lifecycle, e.g. to PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are getting the undefined error means you have lower version of PHP.

The function is supported after `PHP 5.2.2`

> SplFileInfo::getRealPath
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.2.2)
>
> SplFileInfo::getRealPath — Gets
>   absolute path to file

http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php